# How to pass a date variable through to MySQL request?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to request a sample of my data from MySql with this code:

```
myDate = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="password",
    database="db"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE location = 'loc' && date > '%s'"
cursor.execute(sql, myDate)
final_result = cursor.fetchall()

return final_result
```

I am getting the error `ValueError: Could not process parameters` and I am not sure why. When I manually enter the string `'2020-05-31 00:00:00'` and remove `myDate` from the execute statement it gives me my desired results so I think it was something to do with my syntax rather than my parameter.

Comment: I think this solve your issue, if it doesn't I'll be happy to re-open the post. But since there's no debugging information in your post I assume one of the answers in the other thread helps.

Comment: I went through this thread and it didn't seem to solve my problem. I'll add some to my post.

Comment: I found the error. I need my execute statement to be ```cursor.execute(sql, (myDate,))```